# Round off the area points in Highcharts Polar

Tags: highcharts

Is there is a way to round off the area points and make them less pointed when used in the polar chart?

I have tried the 'areaspline', but with polar chart it's not quite right, as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qwbu6r3t/2/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        polar: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 45,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '°';
            }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 45
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'areaspline',
        name: 'Area spline',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    }, {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Area',
        data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
    }]
});
```

**EDIT**

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27RV3.png)

Comment: If this is what your data looks like wouldn't it be better to show as is than to add in artificial "pretty" smoothness? Perhaps you can increase your sample granularity (instead of data taken every 45 degrees you do it every 5)? Adding visually pleasing elements to a chart are not necessarily a good idea if it obscures what the data is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override highcharts `Highcharts.seriesTypes.areaSpline.prototype.getPointSpline` with same method but with changed smoothing parameter. (Default 1.5)

```
...
var smoothing = 3, // 1 means control points midway between points, 2 means 1/3 from the point, 3 is 1/4 etc
...
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/q3h6xwog/

Comment: Worked well for the blue area, but when I tested in the black area it got weird [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m198vsr/1/)

Comment: I made a small mistake in example above I've overwritten method for spline not areaspline. I fixed my answer now.

Comment: Now looks like the normal areaspline. I use your new example, changing the areasplinerange.prototype to areaspline.prototype, and the smoothing to 3. The same problem occurs [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3h6xwog/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just change **area** to **areaspline** would do what you want i think so

Comment: I made an edit with what I need. The areaspline is too round. The perfect scenario is something between both.